# Manipulation the Euclidean norm in such a way to make a new vector

Tags: math

Suppose that the Euclidean norm of a vector (V) is computed (as A) then this norm is changed (as B). Is it any way to modify the vector (V) in such way that its norm become B ?
For example:

```
A=[7 3 1];
n1=norm(A);
n2=n1*0.2;
```

Find a new vector that its norm become n2 ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

norm(A*s) = abs(s)*norm(A) (where s is a scalar), so just multiple A by n2/n1.